# Como pegar dados de um Fragment e jogar em uma Activity?

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma classe no java que pega todas as informações e monta toda a estrutura do meu programa. Bem, como que eu faço para pegar um EditText que está no meu fragment e jogar o seu conteúdo para dentro da outra activity.

Exemplo:

O meu fragment chama um layout que possui um campo de comentário. Este fragment é chamada em outra Activity. Na hora de salvar os dados eu preciso pegar os dados digitados pelo usuário neste EditText do Fragment e salvar. Bem já tentei fazer isso, mas sempre dá erro de null pointer excpetion... Também tentei criar uma intent e não consegui. Se fosse com EventBus como que seria? Já tentei pesquisar por toda a internet e não encontrei nada que resolva o problema

Comment: Cara, dá uma olhada nisto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134645/get-edittext-value-from-fragment .... eu não vou tentar postar pois estou sem como tentar reproduzir e também não tenho seu código

Comment: Amigo, verifique o seguinte tópico: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/129380/46186

Answer (score 1):

Uma das maneiras de passar dados entre activities é criando interfaces e implementando, ou via intent que faz mas sentido no seu caso.

**Crie uma classe que será seu conversor**

```
public class ContactInfo implements Parcelable {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int idx;

    // get and set method

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(surname);
        dest.writeInt(idx);
    }

    // Creator
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<contactinfo> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<contactinfo>() {
        public ContactInfo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ContactInfo(in);
        }

        public ContactInfo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ContactInfo[size];
        }
    };

    // "De-parcel object
    public ContactInfo(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        surname = in.readString();
        idx = in.readInt();
    }
}
```

**PAsse os dados da sua activity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
// Contact Info
ContactInfo ci = createContact("Francesco", "Surviving with android", 1);
i.putExtra("contact", ci);
```

**Pegue esses dados em outra activity**

```
Intent i  = getIntent();
ContactInfo ci = i.getExtras().getParcelable("contact");
```

Mais informações: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2015/05/android-parcelable-tutorial-list-class.html