# Pegar dados de 3 fragments

Tags: android, android-fragment, crud

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação android e nela tenho uma activity com 3 fragments(tabs), onde cada um contém uma parte de um formulário e no último tenho um botão salvar. Minha dificuldade está em como fazer para pegar os dados dos 3 fragments no momento em que eu clicar no botão salvar. Li em alguns lugares para criar uma classe "transporte" para pegar esses dados mas não consegui entender muito bem.

Comment: Uma solução é cada um dos *Fragments* ter um método que retorne os dados do formulário referentes a cada um deles. Esses métodos serão chamados na *Activity* para construir o formulário completo. O botão "salvar" deverá estar na *Activity*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comunicação entre *Fragments* e a *Activity* principal que faz uso deles pode ser feita através de *Interfaces*.

Cada *Fragment* da sua tela deve declarar uma *interface* com um ou mais **métodos de comunicação**, que serão responsáveis pela atualização dos dados na classe que implementar tal *interface* (no caso, esta classe seria a própria Activity).

Vamos a um exemplo. Primeiro o vamos ver o *fragment* que declara a interface de comunicação:

```
public class ExemploFragment extends Fragment {

    // declaração da interface de comunicação
    public interface InterfaceComunicao {

        // aqui, um ou mais métodos de comunicação
        void setIdade(int idade); // por exemplo, este método retorna a idade inserida no fragment
    }

    /* variável que representa quem vai receber a atualização dos dados, 
       no caso a activity principal, que vai implementar a interface de comunicação */
    private InterfaceComunicao listener; 

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

        /* 
            onAttach faz parte do ciclo de vida do fragment, é executado
                quando o fragment é associado à activity
        */

        super.onAttach(activity);

        if (activity instanceof InterfaceComunicao) {
            listener = (InterfaceComunicao) activity;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Activity deve implementar ExemploFragment.InterfaceComunicao");
        }
    }

    // um evento qualquer disparado pelo usuário, por exemplo um click de botão
    public void onClickBotaoQualquer() {

        /* 
            - chama o método de comunicação para atualizar o valor que o usuário informou na tela
            - neste ponto, ler o valor de uma view, por exemplo TextView na tela
            - para o exemplo configuramos direto o valor 15
        */
        listener.setIdade(15);

    }

}
```

A *activity* onde o *fragment* está associado deve implementar a *interface* de comunicação declarada no *fragment*, no caso **InterfaceComunicao**, e seus respectivos métodos.

```
public class ExemploActivity extends Activity implements ExemploFragment.InterfaceComunicao {

    .
    .
    .

    // este é o método de comunicação declarado na interface
    // quando o fragment chamar listener.setIdade(15); este é o método que será executado
    @Override
    public setIdade(int idade) {
        /*
            neste ponto, recupera o valor recebido do fragment e 
            implementa o código que desejar
        */ 
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Esta abordagem garante a independência do *fragment* em relação a *activity* principal, ou seja **desacoplamento**.

Desta forma você pode usar seu *fragment* em qualquer outro ponto da sua aplicação, bastando para isso que a *activity* que deseja usá-lo implemente a *interface* de comunicação.

Para saber mais: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Olá boa tarde, senhores tenho um problema identico onde preciso obter os dados de três Tabs , onde estão fragment com campos de cadastro esta abordagem de usar interface (consta na documentação de fragments) mais ao meu ver não é muito boa, quando o método da interface seria disparado? tem que levar em conta o comportamento do viewPager  o ideal seria qdo o usuário navegasse para a outra tab, tenho tentado na activity usando o adapter do viewPager e chegar na view do fragment mais sem sucesso.