# Passagem de valores entre Fragmento e Actividade

Tags: android

Tenho um fragmento que é constituido por vários botões. O objetivo é que quando eu carregue num desses botões o `fragment` desapareça e passa o valor associado a esse botão para a actividade que está em background. O que está a acontecer é que quando carrego no botão, o fragmento não desaparece e a actividade não recebe o valor do botão. Estou a usar `Callback`.Não tenho qualquer erro ou excepção.

Código do Fragmento:

```
(...)
 public HoroscopeChoice() {}
    /******************************
     * Callback
     ********/
    public static void setOnInfoChangedListener(OnInfoChangedListener callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    public interface OnInfoChangedListener {
        public void onInfoChanged(String horosocopo);
     }
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_horoscope_choice,
                container, false);

        Button aquarius;
        aquarius  = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.aquarius1);

        final int id = view.getId();

        View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String horoscopo = onClick2(v.getId());
                Log.d("HoroscopeChoice", "ao clicar no botao->"+horoscopo);
                mCallback.onInfoChanged(horoscopo);
            }
        };

        aquarius.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
(...)
```

Código da Atividade:

```
(...)
public void onInfoChanged(String horoscopo) {
        Log.d("SchedulerActivity","OnInfoChanged na Scheduler->"+horoscope);

        mHoroscopeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dailyHoroscope4);
        mHoroscopeDisplay.setText(horoscopo);
    }
```

Quando faço `Log.d` no fragmento obtenho o horoscopo, já na actividade aparece vazio. O que me falta fazer?

Comment: Amigo, aqui tem uma solução para seu problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129013/pegar-dados-de-3-fragments/129380#129380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A unica coisa que faltava no meu fragmento e que descobri depois era o:

```
dismiss()
```

para ele desaparecer quando se carrega no botão.

Answer (score 3):

Olá, prothfind. Para começarmos, a ideia é que sua Activity implemente uma interface que o Fragment conheça e chame. Então, vamos criar a tal interface que será chamada quando houve o click no fragment:

```
public interface OnFragmentButtonClickListener  {
    public void onButtonClick();
}
```

E vamos então fazer com que a Activity herde dessa interface e implemente o método:

```
public class MinhaActivity extends AppCompact implements OnFragmentButtonClickListener {

    //... Outros métodos comuns da Activity

    public void onButtonClick() {
       //O botão do fragment foi clicado, faça o que tem que fazer na activity!
    }

}
```

Certo, no método `onAttach()` do seu fragment , que é chamado durante o ciclo de vida do fragment quando uma o fragment é anexado a Activity, capture a Activity usando polimorfismo para termos em mãos uma instância dê OnFragmentButtonClickListener. Dessa forma:

```
public void FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

   OnFragmentButtonClickListener onFragmentButtonClickListener

   @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        if(context instanceof OnFragmentButtonClickListener) {
            onFragmentButtonClickListener = (OnFragmentButtonClickListener) context;
        }
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    //Métodos comuns ao fragment
}
```

Agora, no onClickListener do seu button chame a interface que é implementada pela Activity para que assim a Activity possa corresponder ao click no fragment:

```
fragmentButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       //onFragmentButtonClickListener.onButtonClick(); Lembrando que onFragmentButtonClickListener pode ser null caso a activity não implemente a interface.
    } 
});
```

Porque prefiro essa resposta a do João Gouveia? Pela abstração. Na resposta do João Gouveia você está prendendo o seu Fragment a MyActivity e isso pode te trazer alguns problemas, além de estar quebrando algumas das boas práticas. Pode ser que seu fragment seja anexado a várias outras Activities além do MyActivity. Também pode acontecer que seu fragment no futuro deixe de estar anexado a MyActivity, o que gerará uma busca de referências para dar manutenção. Trabalhar com interfaces torna seu código mais desacoplado e com melhor escalabilidade. Abs!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma variável na sua activity, além de um setter, e "settar" o valor dela de dentro do fragment:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private String horoscopo;

    public void setHoroscopo(String horoscopo) {
        this.horoscopo = horoscopo;
    }
}
```

e no fragment você chama:

```
((MyActivity) getActivity).setHoroscopo(horoscopo);
```

Comment: Não é uma boa ideia porque isso acopla esse Fragment a essa Activity específica. Se quiser reaproveitar em outra Activity (que é uma das principais vantagens do Fragment), não vai conseguir.

Comment: Discordo que essa seja uma das principais vantagens do fragment, normalmente fragments são usados de forma especifica mesmo (acoplados a uma activity especifica). De qualquer forma você consegue sempre generalizar: if (getActivity instaceof MyActivity) ...

Comment: Isso não é generalizar. Você está deixando de acoplar a uma pra acoplar a duas. Se sua ideia de extensibilidade é o uso de `instanceof`, você ainda não entendeu bem o [O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) de SOLID.